# Stack Implementation using Generics in java

Tags: java, generics, stack

I get this error

```
ArrayStack.java uses unchecked Recompile with -Xint:unchecked for details
```

Is there any error with this line

```
S= (T[])(new Object [N]) ;
```

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning. And it's unavoidable as long as you're using `(T[])(new Object[N])`.

Comment: This has been covered before -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java